# How to remove grey shadow on the top UIWebView when overscroll in swift?

Tags: swift2

I'm using UIWebView for show a simple HTML page. When I scroll the page (over the top or over the bottom) a shadow gray appears behind. Please provide me solution in swift.

Comment: can you attach the image of it?

Answer (score 2):

you just have to set navigationbar translucent to false

navigation.navigationBar.translucent = false

Answer (score 1):

And this is the answer for Objective-C:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```